# Создать своё событие на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Возможно ли создать своё событие на jquery? Допустим нужно выполнять какое то действие, если у определенного контейнера сменился класс. Проблема в том что класс меняется программно в очень многих местах и не хочется искать все эти места. Хочется написать что-то вроде:

```
$('#block').on('addClass', function() {...});
```

Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Свое событие создать можно. Но мало его создать - его еще вызывать надо. Поэтому собственные события вам зедсь не помогут.

Answer (score 3):

Да. В местах, где вы программно меняете класс, можете добавить .trigger('addClass');

Тогда пример вашего кода выше заработает.

Можно так же переопределить метод .addClass(), но я считаю это дурным тоном.

Пример:

```
// Create a closure
(function(){
    // Your base, I'm in it!
var originalAddClassMethod = jQuery.fn.addClass;

jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
    // Execute the original method.
    var result = originalAddClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );

    // trigger a custom event
    jQuery(this).trigger('addClass');

    // return the original result
    return result;
}
})();

// document ready function
$(function(){
    $("#YourExampleElementID").on('addClass', function(){ 
        //do stuff here
    });
});
```

Ссылки:

[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Это здорово, но в вопросе я написал "Проблема в том что класс меняется программно в очень многих местах и не хочется искать все эти места". Так что решение не подходит

Comment: Есть возможность переопределить .addClass(), добавив ему проверку на список добавляемых вами классов, но, как по мне, это очень дурной тон.

Comment: Не обязательно добавлять в `.addClass()` проверку, можно там сделать `.trigger('addClass')`.

Comment: Вобщем-то неплохо, но переопределять метод действительно не хочется, к тому же код который добавляет класс к контейнеру написан на чистом js без использования jquery. Не думаю что в этом случае переопределение `addClass` сработает.

Comment: @AlMr то есть постойте, добавление класса идет не через `jquery`? Ну тогда вам поможет найти все места изменения класса и добавлять туда событие. Ну или использовать `MutationObserver`.